# How can I make curve endpoints of various spiral curves parallel with an axis in geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, mathematics

How can I make curve endpoints of various spiral curves **parallel with an axis in geometry nodes.**

Example: I create a curve spiral and use a circle as the profile.  As you see the end points are **skewed / at an angle** (**see red arrows**)

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

I'm trying to get them to be parallel with the axis (lined up)

Comment: i doubt there is an easy way, I think you will have to go the "hard" way and manually position the handle position points of your endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant result, but it's relatively easy to calculate the index values of those endpoint vertices, so you could simply select them and `Set Position` their *Y* values to $0$:

[image]

It would break if you set the `Spiral` resolution too high, and it doesn't preserve the curvature of the tips, but could be good enough depending on your purpose.